# AWS - API Gateway, Lambda Authorizers, and ‘challenge/response’ style authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an automation that takes a Webhook from a service and posts it to Slack. The webhook goes to an API Gateway URL, authorizes through a Lambda authorizer function, and then goes to the Lambda function. This process is outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).

The verification is in the header["authentication"] field, which is validated by the authorizer. I scoped that text in the authorizer, and it passes it to the Lambda proxy as `authenticationToken`. If validated, a certificate is created and the webhook is passed to Lambda. This has all been working for a few months.

This year, as many companies tend to do, the service with the webhook is deprecating this auth method, and changing their authentication to a "Challenge-Response Check" style. So, the webhook sends a validation webhook, and the authorizer needs to make a hashed token out of several headers, including timestamp, and then the authorizer passes that hashed token back to the webhook, before sending the real webhook payload. Here is a node/express sample of how to do this:

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  var response

  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.headers)

  // construct the message string
  const message = `v0:${req.headers['x-zm-request-timestamp']}:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`

  const hashForVerify = crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.ZOOM_WEBHOOK_SECRET_TOKEN).update(message).digest('hex')

  // hash the message string with your Webhook Secret Token and prepend the version semantic
  const signature = `v0=${hashForVerify}`

  // you validating the request came from Zoom https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/webhook-reference#notification-structure
  if (req.headers['x-zm-signature'] === signature) {

    // Zoom validating you control the webhook endpoint https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/webhook-reference#validate-webhook-endpoint
    if(req.body.event === 'endpoint.url_validation') {
      const hashForValidate = crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.ZOOM_WEBHOOK_SECRET_TOKEN).update(req.body.payload.plainToken).digest('hex')

      response = {
        message: {
          plainToken: req.body.payload.plainToken,
          encryptedToken: hashForValidate
        },
        status: 200
      }


....
```

Is this methodology supported by the authorizer/Lambda method? The APIG authorizer would need to send several headers to the Lambda authorizer function, vs just the one. I see a new feature that is changing the authorizer `Type` to `Request` (from `Token`), but I was not able to pass the headers to the auth function that way, after re-creating and re-deploying the APIG.

Or, should I get rid of the authorizer all together, and just do my authentication on the actual Lambda?

Or, should I start to use Lambda's newer URL feature, and get rid of APIG all together?

What is the best workflow in this use case?

Any advice or links appreciated.